# Github Actions Flutter CI Error: No version of NDK matched

Tags: flutter, github, android-ndk, continuous-integration, github-actions

[Project Repository](https://github.com/NeoMindStd/HoliNoti)

I've been push the [commit](https://github.com/NeoMindStd/HoliNoti/commit/d7322bd679a12364862aec685b9e07de22374e83)

but, I got [error](https://github.com/NeoMindStd/HoliNoti/runs/577484735?check_suite_focus=true)

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols'.


> No version of NDK matched the requested version 20.0.5594570. Versions available locally: 21.0.6113669
```

Below is the CI code([Flutter CI - Customer](https://github.com/NeoMindStd/HoliNoti/blob/master/.github/workflows/flutter-customer.yml)):

```
name: Flutter CI - Customer

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - holinoti_customer/**
      - .github/workflows/flutter-customer.yml

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - holinoti_customer/**

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.0.0
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 11.0.2
    - name: Android NDK toolchain Setup
      uses: ravinderjangra/android-ndk-toolchain-setup@0.1
      with: 
        api: '21'
        arch: 'arm'
        install-location: 'toolchains'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1.1.1
      with:
        flutter-version: '1.12.x' # you can use 1.12
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: flutter pub get
      working-directory: holinoti_customer
    - name: Test Build
      run: flutter build apk
      working-directory: holinoti_customer
```

In my local project, I set the ndk path in android studio's project structure

[image]

However, this solution is can't applied on Github Action

So, I tried to use `Android NDK toolchain Setup`, but still fail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the local.properties file, set `ndkVersion` in your build.gradle to match the one available on your CI server. i.e.

```
android {
    ndkVersion "21.1.6352462"
}
```

(I'm assuming that your CI has updated to make r21b available since then, otherwise use the 21.0.blah version from the error message.)

That way your CI and your local build both use the same version.

That was the motivation for this change, btw: keeping builds reproducible. Previously your CI and your local builds were using different versions of the NDK, and that can be a surprising and annoying source of bugs :)

Comment: What about installing another NDK version on the Github Actions agent? Is there anyway to install NDK from command line? Where the NDK files should be on Github Actions agent?

Comment: Setting that property in your build.gradle does download the NDK if needed. For AGP 4.1+ it will be downloaded when needed even without the above setting.

Comment: Very helpful! Been stuck on this for days a similar error I had led me here. Also thanks OP for posting this question. Why was this needed anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Check updates of SDK Tools update the NDK and CMake tools.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.